# How can I transcode a library of DVD Rips into a more compact/accessible format?

Tags: dvd, media-center, handbrake, media-center-extender, transcode

I have a hard drive that was filled with DVD copies of movies that I own, used in conjunction with [My Movies](http://www.mymovies.dk/) to allow the children to easily watch the DVDs without having to mess around with and potentially damage the actual physical disks (which are safely stored).

I now have an XBox 360 connected to the TV, and the XBox 360 is configured as a Media Center Extender, so that we can use Media Center from the XBox to view all of our content.  However, the XBox complains that the movies on the PC are in an invalid/inaccessible format.

I have had success with using [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) in order to convert the movies to a different format;  these transcoded movies play perfectly fine on the XBox.  However, I have many many movies on the PC, and Handbrake does not seem to have any "automatically convert all below this directory" mode.  Is there existing free (or paid, but

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Handbrake itself can't batch-process, but if you're already familiar with Handbrake, why not use [Handbrake Batch Encoder](http://videoscripts.wordpress.com/downloads/) for Windows? It's really not worth switching to another application if you've already found one and tweaked it.

Here are …

- [Usage Guide](http://videoscripts.wordpress.com/how-to-use/)
- [Features](http://videoscripts.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/handbrake-batch-gui/)
- [Download](http://www.box.net/shared/i6exaxr438)

And there's a [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5702144/handbrake-batch-encoder-simplifies-multiple-video-conversions) as well. From the same page, you might be interested in [WatchFolder](http://videoscripts.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/watchfolder-for-handbrake/), which allows you to set up a folder that is "watched". This means, every video dropped into it will automatically be converted using Handbrake.

[image]

Comment: That... looks EXACTLY like what I had in mind.  Will test when I get home.  Good find :)